# Zend Framework addMultiOption adding custom parameters like "rel" for options

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-select

Im using Zend, and we have a form thats put together through a series of functions. One in particular addMultiOption, of which is being pulled in from a DB (from where I dunno, cause if I could alter the query, that'd be much easier and better all around. Anyway that said I need to add a "rel" attribute to every option /option so I can preform a task on the option via jquery when that option is selected, its not all options but some, options that don't have extra functionality would have a rel of 0 where as the ones with actions will have a rel of "one" this comes from the DB so. I am trying to figure out how I can add extra attributes outside of value

does the Zend Framework support this, if not how can I achieve this? I found what I thought was a nice post here earlier about it, but turns out it just doesn't work for me

Comment: Could you add the ref tag via jquery when the page is loaded?

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401412/zend-form-custom-attribute-in-select-option

Comment: I could but that would require me to run an addtional query for the options in the select, then run down the options in the select to see if any of them have the matching criteria, to then add to them what I need from them. Overall trying to avoid the query process as the query can get quie large in results

Comment: That link is unfortunately one of the ones that just don't work for me. I get an error for the addOption that I could not back trace the issue on.

Answer (score 5):

Using addMultiOption($value,$label) I just set the value parameter to something like:

```
$value = $id . '" ref="' . $ref;
```

and when it renders you get:

```
<option value="<idValue>" ref="<refValue"><labelValue></option>
```

Hope this helps....

Okay, value gets escaped but optionClasses does not so inside the loop that adds the addMultiOptions(val,lable) I do something like this:

```
$optionClasses[<val>] = 'ref_' . <val> . '" ref="' . <ref>;
```

and then after the loop just do a setAttrib('optionClasses',$optionClasses)

And that actually works...

So here is an example where I will define an array that might be a recordset from a db query with the three parts we are going to use; id, code and offset

```
$records = array( array('id' => 1, 'code' => 'Code 1', 'offset' => 4),
                  array('id' => 2, 'code' => 'Code 2', 'offset' => 5),
                  array('id' => 3, 'code' => 'Code 3', 'offset' => 6)
           );
```

and I will use this in a form element definition ( in a class that extends Zend_Form) for a select where the options have an attribute called 'offset' that will have the 'offset' value from the array

```
$e = $this->createElement('select', 'code_id');
$e->setLabel('Event Type:')
    ->setAttrib('size', 1);
$optionClasses = array();
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $optionClass = 'xcode_' . $record['id'] . '" xoffset="' . $record['offset'];
    $optionClasses[$record['id']] = $optionClass;
    $e->addMultiOption($record['id'],$record['code']);
}
$e->setAttrib('optionClasses', $optionClasses);
$this->addElement($e);
```

and when this is rendered, it produces a select element like

```
<select name="code_id" id="code_id">
    <option value="1" class="xcode_1" xoffset="4" selected="selected">Code 1</option>
    <option value="2" class="xcode_2" xoffset="5">Code 2</option>
    <option value="3" class="xcode_3" xoffset="6">Code 3</option>
</select>
```

and then you can get to the offset of the selected option with jQuery using

```
 var xoffset = $("#code_id").find("option:selected").attr("xoffset");
```

this works because the optionClasses resulting class attribute does not get escaped by the rendering method like the value attribute does.

Comment: Actually, this did not work. The value get escaped and is all treated as one value rather than value and ref attributes. Still pursueing this though and will update.

Comment: The optionClasses approach does work, the first attempt at trying to change the way value was used is what did not work. I hope these comments are not confusing things... I will put together an example that I can add to the answer to try to make things clear.

Comment: thanks a lot! this has helped a lot. Saved me from creating a custom element and view helper