# How to set custom data attbributes with zend form select?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element

I am using Zend_Form_Element_Select to create a select form element.  Here's how the inner HTML is rendered:

```
<option value="9" label="Biscuits">Biscuits</option>    
<option value="10" label="Scones">Scones</option>
<option value="11" label="Cakes">Cakes</option>
```

Now, I want to be able to include a custom data attribute, `data-qty`,  with each option, per the following example:

```
<option value="9" label="Biscuits" data-qty="27">Biscuits</option>  
<option value="10" label="Scones" data-qty="12">Scones</option>
<option value="11" label="Cakes" data-qty="21">Cakes</option>
```

I can't see any way to do this out of the box so I think I'll need to extend the select element, create a new decorator, or some such solution.  Any ideas?

Comment: May this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401412/zend-form-custom-attribute-in-select-option